# MySQL instance configuration

Tags: mysql, configuration, windows-installer

I am trying to build a installer to Install MySQL for my application. Later create a server instance for it using [MySQLInstanceConfig](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-windows-excerpt/5.1/en/mysql-config-wizard-cmdline.html) running it in a batch file.

```
mysqlinstanceconfig.exe -i -q ServiceName=MySQL55 RootPassword=root 
ServerType=DEVELOPMENT ConnectionUsage=DSS   DatabaseType=MYISAM Port=3307 
SkipNetworking=no RootPassword=root

set mysql_cmd="GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'root' WITH GRANT OPTION;"

mysql.exe -uroot -proot -e %mysql_cmd%
```

or

```
MySQLInstanceConfig.exe -i -q "-lE:\UEM\mysql_install_log.txt" »
"-nMySQL Server 5.5" "-pC:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5" -v5.5.11 »
"-tmy-template.ini" "-cC:\mytest.ini" ServerType=DEVELOPMENT DatabaseType=MIXED »
ConnectionUsage=DSS Port=3307 ServiceName=MySQL55 RootPassword=root
```

The following script does work with MySQL 5.0 but not with 5.5 . If I try to check whats wrong and run the installer manually I get this dialog and later changing the instance makes it to work.[image: MySQL instance configuration error].
How do I counter this?